# Center horizontally absolute div in another floating div

Tags: javascript, css, html, stylesheet

I have the following markup:

```
.container {
  top: 50px;
  width: 800px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
.left {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  float: left;
}
.right {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  float: right;
}
.messageWrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  bottom: 0;
  max-height: 100%;
  min-height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 170px;
}
.message {
  min-height: 20px;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    ...
  </div>

  <div class="right">
    <div class="messageWrapper">
      <div class="message"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This produces the following result:

[image]

What I am trying to do is to horizontally center yellou div in a green one. It should stay in the same vertical position, but sligthly move to right to be centered in green div.

This question gets more and more downvotes. I am asking all downvoters to post a comment under this question. This is just ridiculous. What is wrong with this question??

Comment: Do it yourself. No one is here to code for you.

Comment: Was it so difficult to include your code in the question?

Comment: what do you mean `the same vertical position as in example`?

Comment: When I see something like **I want!** in a question, I just ignore it.

Comment: Also, why did you tag this primarily as javascript? There is no JS in your code

Comment: I can not achieve this... If I could i wont post this message. Can anybody help please?

Comment: There is another SO post [here] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939914/vertically-align-text-in-a-div) that is similar. its in CSS2, but im sure you can take it as a foundation and build from there.

Comment: @giorgi-nakeuri take a look at css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/ it's a great resource on horizontal and vertical centering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the css elements you need to change:

```
.right {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: green;
    float: right;
    position: relative; //here
}
.messageWrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    bottom: 0;
    max-height: 100%;
    min-height: 20px;
    width: 170px;
    text-align: center; //here
    width: 100%; //here
    position: absolute;  //here
}

.message {
    min-height: 20px;
    background-color: yellow;
    margin-left: auto; //here
    margin-right: auto; //here
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    width: 80%; //here
}
```

And a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a1Lp2o52/